# How to make old text slide down as new text is added above it?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am feeding text to a div from the top.

The following code gives the newest paragraph a slide-down animation as it is added to the div.

How can I make all paragraphs slide down as the new one is created?
Also, any tips on my code will be greatly appreciated!

HTML:

```
<div id="text">
```

Javascript:

```
function addText(message) {
    var el = document.getElementById('text');
    var p = document.createElement('p');
    p.appendChild(document.createTextNode(message));
    el.insertBefore(p, el.childNodes[0] || null);
    $(p).addClass("reveal");
}
```

CSS:

```
.reveal {
    animation: slide-down 1s;
}

@keyframes slide-down {
  from {
    -moz-transform: translateY(-50px);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50px);
    transform: translateY(-50px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
    transform: translateY(0px);
    -moz-animation: linear;
    -webkit-animation: linear;
    animation: linear;
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you make demo link what you tried?

Comment: You want to new added paragraph display in bottom?

Comment: Your posted question or answer

Comment: I posted question. how to make old paragraphs have slide down effect?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this.

```
function addText(message) {
     $('p').removeClass("reveal");
     setTimeout(function(){ 
        var el = document.getElementById('text');
        var p = document.createElement('p');
        p.appendChild(document.createTextNode(message));
        el.insertBefore(p, el.childNodes[0] || null);
        $('p').addClass("reveal");
     }, 500);
}
addText('Welcome to first paragrap');
```

Then you call second one in console.

Comment: how can I apply this to the el.childNodes[0]?

Comment: right now, that selects all <p> elements on the page, I only want to animate the <p> elements that are within the <div id="text">